# rule to get bjam's callstack or why am I registering 2 identic generators

Tags: build, build-automation, bjam, boost-build

Is there a rule that returns the current call in bjam ?

I know if you call **"bjam.exe -d+10 ..."** it will print you the callstack but your own ECHO's not.

What I intend to do is print the callstack in **generators.register** or any other rules from **generators.jam** to find out from where does this double-register.

Currently I am registering two identical generators and I have no way of findout out why.
And this eventually leads to this:

*Error: ambiguity found when searching for best transformation*

...

Generators that succeeded:

- xxx.link
- xxx.link

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using the built-in [BACKTRACE](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/jam/language.html#jam.language.rules.builtins.utility._backtrace__) rule of bjam. You can also consider using some convenient wrappers around it found in tools/build/v2/kernel/errors.jam if raw BACKTRACE does not give the call stack in a format best appropriate for your case.